# JavaScript Loop stuck beginner

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am trying some loops and in this specific I do not understand why is sumSoFar = 0.
This is a task from Learn Street.com

```
function sum(n) {
    var sumSoFar = 0;
    var currentNumber = 1;

    while (currentNumber <= n) {
        sumSoFar += currentNumber;
        currentNumber += 1;
    }

    return sumSoFar;
}
```

Comment: For what value of `n` that is passed in?  It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kXrV8/

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand why `sumSoFar` is set to 0 at the start of the function?

Comment: This shouldn't happen unless `n<1`

Comment: Had `sumSoFar` not been initialised to zero, `sumSoFar += currentNumber;` would have resulted in **NaN**

Comment: Henry - since you're new here, I'd like to point out that when you post a question, you should check in for the next 30 mins or so to respond to immediate questions that get raised about your question.  That first 30 mins is where your question is going to see the most traffic and if it isn't clear what you were asking or if people guess wrong what you were asking, you will lose most of your chances to get the kind of answer you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sumSoFar` is initialized to zero at the start of the function because the rest of the function uses the `+=` operator which takes the current value of `sumSoFar` and adds a value to that and then assigns the new value back to `sumSoFar`.  If it wasn't initialized to zero, then it would not have an initial value and the first `+=` operation on it would not have the desired result.

Initializing it to zero gives it the desired starting point so that the first time through the while loop, it adds `currentNumber` to that initial value of zero and assigns that to `sumSoFar` which is the desired behavior.

FYI, you can see your function work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kXrV8/ and in the latest version, you can try different input arguments to your `sum(n)` function.

Comment: Added to the jsFiddle in my answer the ability to try any value for `n` in `sum(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't initialize `sumSoFar` to zero you can't add values to it because it wouldn't be a number.